# How to pass data between pages in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

How to pass data between pages  in WPF?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data in the ctor

```
PageSearchFieldFTS nextPage = new PageSearchFieldFTS((GabeLib.FieldDef)SearchFieldSelected, paramAndOr);
SrchItemEditDetail.Content = nextPage;   // SrchItemEditDetail is a frame


public partial class PageSearchFieldFTS : Page
{

    public PageSearchFieldFTS(GabeLib.FieldDef FieldDef, GabeLib.enumAndOr AndOr)
    {
```